# Android Google Play games signin error 12501

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have read many issues and solutions here and tried all of them. I know everybody says it is about sha1 and other configurations but I couldn't get rid of this problem.

Trying to implement Google Play Games services to my android project. Project is also created on Firebase Console. I downloaded gogle-services.json and put it on app folder.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

I put screenshots for configs I have made. Trying both debug and release key it gives same error 12501.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
        .requestServerAuthCode(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .build();

GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
Intent intent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
startActivityForResult(intent, RC_SIGN_IN);
```

[image: Firebase config]

[image: Play console setup app signing]

[image: Play games service config]

[image: Cloud console credentials]

[image: Android debug key]

Comment: GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);
        startActivityForResult( signInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN );

Comment: Thx but it doesn't make a difference I had tried before

Comment: Try to sign in. Please read official documentation.

Comment: yes I already have done everything what the docs say. please check the screenshots :)